# Redirection Loop Issue: Adding Trailing Slash Results in Multiple Redirects on Apache Server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use my website this technology Centos 7, Apache and PHP 7.4

I faced this issue adding trailing slash results in multiple redirects. My website URL is `https://example.com/post/test`
but when I add trailing slash `https://example.com/post/test/` then test redirect-checker.org showing results as below.

How can I solve this problem?

**redirect-checker.org checker results**

CONGRATULATION. Everything seems to be fine.

```
https://example.com/post/test/
301 Moved Permanently
http://example.com/post/test
301 Moved Permanently
https://example.com/post/test
200 OK
```

```
**.htaccess file**
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: There's nothing in your `.htaccess` file that would cause such redirects. (The URL is _changing_ from `test` to `stashed` and there is nothing in your `.htaccess` file that mentions "stashed".) Maybe the problem is in your PHP code? "CONGRATULATION. Everything seems to be fine." - ???

Comment: Presumably you see the same redirect chain when you request this URL directly? (You shouldn't need an external checker, unless you suspect others are seeing a different response than you. The browser has all the tools you need to check redirect chains.)

Comment: Sorry! I type mistake edit my problem text please check again.

Comment: Unfortunately, my comment still applies (the `test` vs `stashed` issue was just one thing)... you appear to be seeing a HTTPS to HTTP redirect (before redirecting back to HTTPS) - this is not possible with the directives as posted (the first rule explicitly redirects to HTTPS and the second rule preserves the protocol - unless you have a server config issue). Is this all you have in the `.htaccess` file? Is the `.htaccess` file being processed at all?? Do you have access to the Apache server config?

Comment: You see a redirection from https to http? And that without any further warning on the client side? Sorry, but I very mich doubt that.